# How to Fix this issue 'TypeError' object has no attribute 'value'?

Tags: python

In Connectivity I can't able to insert values in SSMS
Geting Error !

```
Connection Closed
'TypeError' object has no attribute 'value'
```

---

```
            print (soup_ExeName,"|",soup_PreCompany,"|",soup_NewTitle,"|",soup_Company,"|",soup_tenur,"|",soup_CRM)
            
            try:
                records = [
                    [soup_ExeName, soup_PreCompany, soup_NewTitle, soup_Company, soup_tenur, soup_CRM]
                ]
                
                DRIVER = 'SQL Server'
                SERVER_NAME = 'SRIRAM\SQLEXPRESS'
                DATABASE_NAME = 'DataSet'

                Conn_string = f"""
                    Driver={{{DRIVER}}};
                    Server={SERVER_NAME};
                    Database={DATABASE_NAME};
                    Trust_Connection=yes;
                """

                try:
                    Conn = odbc.connect(Conn_string)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e)
                    print('Task is Terminated')
                    sys.exit()
                else:
                    cursor = Conn.cursor()

                insert_statement = """
                    INSERT INTO RecordSet
                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
                """

                **try:
                    for record in records:
                        print(record)
                        cursor.execdirect(insert_statement, record) **--> 'TypeError' object has no attribute 'value'**
                        # cursor.executemany(insert_statement, record)
                except Exception as e:
                    cursor.rollback()
                    print(e.value)
                    print('Transaction Rolled Back')
                else:
                    print('Record Inserted Sucessfully')
                    cursor.commit()
                    Conn.close()
                finally:
                    if Conn.connected == 1:
                        print('Connection Closed')
                        Conn.close()
                
            except Exception as e: 
                print(e)**
            #----------------------------------------------------------------------------

        return Linkedin_URL
        
    print(GetLinkedin())
    
except Exception as e: 
    print(e)
```

Comment: Write us the given error please.

Comment: it is telling you that you can't do `e.value` (without raising an exception)

Comment: Exception `e` has no attribute value, as you try to access, isn't it clear enough ?

Comment: `except Exception as e:`, here you've assigned the exception that raised to `e` and `print(e.value)` here you've asked it to print `value` attribute of it, considering exceptions in python, there is no attribute called `value` to any exception... that's why that error raised.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you try to print error message here.

```
  except Exception as e:
                    cursor.rollback()
                    print(e.value)
                    print('Transaction Rolled Back')
```

[Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) in python is an objects and not necessarily have an `value` attribute.

If you want to display error message you can just print an error object

```
  except Exception as e:
                    cursor.rollback()
                    print(e)
                    print('Transaction Rolled Back')
```

Comment: [Arianne M Collette, Morgan Stanley, Chief Operating Officer, Morgan Stanley, 4 mos, Not in CRM]
'type' object is not subscriptable
Transaction Rolled Back
Connection Closed

Comment: I'm trying to insert the data in SSMS (SQL DB). The Error which I get - 'type' object is not subscriptable how to solve this error ?